# Password expired error trying to authenticate a user

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

All,

I'm working on a WP8 app with facebook integration and having issues simply authenticating the user. I've followed the instructions on the facebook developer pages but to no avail. I've tried both using the SDK and direct hand-built URI, but with the same results.

When doing it "by hand", I built the URL as below (data altered to protect the innocent)

```
String url = "fbconnect://authorize?" +
                     "client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&" +
                     "scope=email,basic_info&" +
                     "redirect_uri=msft-YYYYYYYYY%3a%2f%2ffacebookrelaunch";
```

Every time I try this, I get an error in the FB app of "Your password may have expired. Please log out and log in again". The response callback simply contains:

error=Unknown+error&error_code=2003&error_description=An+unknown+error+occurred+while+trying+to+authenticate+with+Facebook&error_reason=An+unknown+error+occurred&state=

I've tried to log out and log back in again, but I get the same thing. I've uninstalled the FB app from my phone and tried with a clean install, same result.

Right now I'm at a loss because this all seems like it should be very straight forward.

Comment: Refer this blog http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/

Comment: Thank you, but that blog doesn't actually cover the issue at hand. I am already displaying the app and have that working but it's returning an error which is unexplainable.